# prevent duplicate (Unique Passport)

Tags: java, oop, computer-science

I'm trying to prevent user to add 2 attendee with the same passport I tried many things as making Boolean variable to check if attendee was added before or no but I have failed all of my attempts can't really think of a way to make this

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Workshop Available_Work_Shops = new Workshop();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String passportNumber, workshop;
            boolean isAttendeeMatch;
            ArrayList<Attendee> attendeeList = new ArrayList<>();
            int choice;
            do {
                System.out.println("1. Add New Attendee");
                System.out.println("2. Add Existing Attendee to Workshop");
                System.out.println("3. Remove Attendee from Workshop");
                System.out.println("4. Print WorkShop List");
                System.out.println("5. Print All Attendees");
                System.out.println("0. Close Program");
                System.out.println("Please Enter a number to choose");
                choice = sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextLine();
                switch (choice) {

                    case 1 -> {
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("Adding New Attendee");
                        System.out.println("____________________");
                        System.out.print("Please Enter Attendee Name: ");
                        String Attendee_name = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Please Enter Attendee Passport Number: ");
                        String Attendee_passport = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Please Enter Attendee Age: ");
                        String Attendee_Age = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Please Enter Attendee Phone Number: ");
                        String phone = sc.nextLine();
                        attendeeList.add(new Attendee(Attendee_name, Attendee_Age, Attendee_passport, phone));
                        for (Attendee attendee : attendeeList) {
                            if (attendeeList.contains(attendee.PassportNumber)) {
                                System.out.println("Existing User Found please enter '3' to remove the duplicate user");
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Issue

Let's focus on these two lines

```java
...
for (Attendee attendee : attendeeList) {
  if (attendeeList.contains(attendee.PassportNumber)) {
...
```

Since you've defined the `attendeeList` to be an `ArrayList` holding `Attendee` objects, you should be passing `Attendee` objects to `attendeeList.contains()`. While the `contains()` function [does accept any Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#i6), it will only return true if one of the List's elements `.equals()` the object you pass in.

#### The Solution

I'd recommend changing this block of code...

```java
attendeeList.add(new Attendee(Attendee_name, Attendee_Age, Attendee_passport, phone));
for (Attendee attendee : attendeeList) {
  if (attendeeList.contains(attendee.PassportNumber)) {
    System.out.println("Existing User Found please enter '3' to remove the duplicate user");
  }
}
```

... to something like this

```java
Attendee potentialAttendee = new Attendee(Attendee_name, Attendee_Age, Attendee_passport, phone)
// Check if the potentialAttendee's passport number is already used by someone in the list.
boolean passportRegistered = false;
for (Attendee attendee : attendeeList) {
  if (attendee.PassportNumber.equals(potentialAttendee.PassportNumber) {
    System.out.println("That user passport number has already been registered. It can't be added again.");
    passportRegistered = true;
  }
}
// Only add the potentialAttendee if his/her passport number wasn't already used by someone in the list.
if (!passportRegistered) {
  attendeeList.add(potentialAttendee);
}
```

The key difference is that you shouldn't add the potentialAttendee to the list until you've first validated that he/she meets the requirements to be added to that list.

#### Potential Enhancements

- Store the Attendees in a HashMap instead of an ArrayList. If you key off of the PassportNumber, then by definition you can't have two participants with the same PassportNumber in the collection of attendees.
- Java has a nice Streaming API that could make the validation even closer to a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, I see a few issues that would break the code:

1. You're adding the attendee to the list and then checking if it exists in the list afterwards (which it always will after adding it if checking correctly).
2. `if (attendeeList.contains(attendee.PassportNumber))` will never return `true` because you're checking if the entire `List` has an object that is equal to the `PassportNumber` in it (as opposed to the `PassportNumber` in the object). It should be `if(attendee.getPassportNumber().equals(Attendee_passport))`.

Not sure how much of a beginner you are but it might also be useful to look into things like naming conventions (in general Java variables should be named with a lowercase first letter and each new word has an uppercase letter), using `List<Attendee>` as the declared variable type instead of `ArrayList`, and things like filtering lists using Java Streams to see if something exists already. Java also has `Set` as an alternative to `List` for when you only want to store unique values (there's other differences between `List` and `Set` so make sure you look into it if you want to use it).